# Is field mode "REPEATED" not supported for external tables in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, external-tables

Are repeated fields secretly not supported for external tables in BigQuery? The UI validator always displays the error message `Unsupported field mode: REPEATED` no matter what the query is, even if I'm not trying to select any of the columns with that mode. Running the query anyway produces this same error.

Obviously I had to specify my own schema as the autodetect only ever seems to come back with the `NULLABLE` mode for every field. BQ doesn't have any problems with the [tables.inset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/insert) call with my schema, and creates the table successfully. FWIW I tried including the schema alternately in the [root table resource](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#resource:-table) as well as the [ExternalDataConfiguration](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#ExternalDataConfiguration) object, and they both worked fine.

I'll go ahead and mention that I also searched this error on google.com and got **0** results. Google went as far as to write an entire section of BigQuery documentation about the [limitations of external data sources](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources#external_data_source_limitations), and nowhere do they say that `REPEATED` mode is not supported. So what gives??

Comment: I believe the reason why BigQuery's autodetect always decides the mode should be `NULLABLE` for every field is to allow for empty trailing rows after your range, which I'd imagine is a common occurrence for many external data sources for example a Google Sheet. But this doesn't explain why an external table's `REPEATED` mode would be secretly unsupported

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your query?